# How to represent this response using Dataweave?

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a HTTP requester in my flow which calls AmericanFlightsAPI, its original GET response is like this:

```
[{
"ID": 1,
"code": "ER38sd",
"price": 400.00,
"departureDate": "2016/03/20",
"origin": "MUA",
"destination": "SFO",
"emptySeats": 0,
"plane": {
    "type": "Boeing 737",
    "totalSeats": 150
}
```

I want to filter these records and show only records containing flights having destination "SFO" and "CLE", like this:

```
{
  "flight_ID": 4,
  "code": "rree1000",
  "destination": {
    "destination": "CLE"
  }
```

Other fields for the filtered destination like ID, Code should also be removed from the response.
What is the Dataweave code to achieve this? Actual API is like this: [Original API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iyeV.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and easy way could be ..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ((value, index) -> (value.destination == 'SFO' or value.destination == 'CLE')) map {
    "flight_ID" : $.ID,
    "code": $.code,
    "destination": {
       "destination": $.destination
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I send a request in Postman, it is saying: "Response code 429 mapped as a failure."

Comment: Thank you so much. After removing the "index" from "(value, index)", it is working exactly as I've mentioned.